Math Olympiad Finite Product Question
This question is from 2017 Shanghai TI Cup Mathematics Competition. Part 1, question 1.
Find the value of the expression: $\frac {2^2} {1 \times 3} \times \frac {4^2} {3 \times 5} \times \frac {6^2} {5 \times 7} \times \,... \,\times \frac {2016^2} {2015 \times 2017}$
Round your answer to 2 decimal places. The use of a graphing calculator is allowed for this question.
My (failed) attempt on the question:
$\frac {2^2} {1 \times 3} \times \frac {4^2} {3 \times 5} \times \frac {6^2} {5 \times 7} \times \,... \,\times \frac {2016^2} {2015 \times 2017}$
$= [\frac {2^2} {3^2} \times \frac {4^2} {5^2} \times \frac {6^2} {7^2} \times \, ... \, \times \frac {2014^2} {2015^2}] \times \frac {2016^2} {2017}$
$= [\frac {2 \times 4 \times 6 \times \,...\,\times2014} {3 \times 5 \times 7 \times \,...\,\times2015}]^2 \times \frac {2016^2} {2017}$
$= [\frac {2^{1007} \times 1007!} {3 \times 5 \times 7 \times \,...\,\times2015}]^2 \times \frac {2016^2} {2017}$
By cancelling common terms in numerator and denominator,
$= [\frac {2^{1007} \times 2 \times 4 \times 6 \times \, ... \, \times1006} {1009 \times 1011 \times 1013 \times \,...\,\times2015}]^2 \times \frac {2016^2} {2017}$
$= [\frac {2^{1510} \times 503!} {1009 \times 1011 \times 1013 \times \,...\,\times2015}]^2 \times \frac {2016^2} {2017}$
I do not know how to continue from here.What I am doing is probably wrong.
The question is basically asking for
$\prod_{i=1}^{1008} \frac {(2i)^2} {(2i-1)(2i+1)}$
$=\prod_{i=1}^{1008} \frac {4i^2} {4i^2-1}$
Can someone please help me? Thank you.

What have you tried?

Notice that a lot of terms get cancelled (check denominator)

Try arranging the terms so that you can think of both the numerator and denominator as some kind of factorial

Sorry for the lousy formatting the first time. It is my first time on this site and I was experimenting with formatting features. I did not expect so many people so see this post within 30 minutes of uploading.

Does this answer your question? Error estimation for the Wallis product

Put $$a_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{2k}{2k-1} \cdot \frac{2k}{2k+1}\right).$$
Your question is about $a_{1008}$. As Anne Bauval already noted, Error estimation for the Wallis product
is almost answer. It's proved there that
$$\exp \left(-\frac{1}{4n+2}\right) < \frac{a_n}{\pi/2} < \exp \left(-\frac{1}{4n+4}\right).$$
Hence
$a_{1008} \approx \pi/2 \approx 1.570796$ with error less than $10^{-6}$.
The answer is $1.57$.

Why not simply (as suggested) vote to close as a duplicate?

@AnneBauval In the first string it's $a_{1013}$, in the last string it's $a_{1008}$, it look's like there's a misprint somewhere. About duplicate: I see that people with much bigger rating (than I have) answer, I supposed that it's a standart way, but after your question I'm not sure:)

Let $$\Omega(n)=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(2i)^2}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}$$
In other words, $$\Omega(n)=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{4i^2}{4i^2-1}$$
According to wolframalpha, this expression has a closed form.
$$\Omega(n)=\frac{\pi \Gamma(n+1)^2}{2\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$
You have to calculate $\Omega(1008)$
I hope you can continue after this. Cheers.

Apply the duplication formula and the reflection formula to get the desired answer.

I have not learnt about duplication and reflection formula in school yet. Thank you for your answer, I will study it now.

@Poopysock don't study it if your aim is math Olympiad...there must be some other elementary way to solve this...wait for some expert to solve it

Yeah that what I was what I was originally thinking. Gamma functions are way too difficult for me. I'm usually taught to manipulate the expression in some way to cancel out terms. Anyways thanks for the help

@Poopysock in which contest was this question asked?? I really can't think of any elementary method to solve this

Can you please complete your answer, i.e. add the details of how the duplication and reflection formulas help to calculate $\frac{\Gamma(1009)^2}{\Gamma\left(1008+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1008+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$?

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad This question is from 2017 Shanghai TI Cup Mathematics Competition. Part 1, question 1.

By inspection the products are quotients of even by odd double factorials squared, except for the last odd factor in the denominator
$$ \prod _{k=1}^{n} \frac{4 k^2}{4 k^2-1}=\frac{((2\ n) !!)^2}{(2\ n+1) \left((2\ n-1) !!\right)^2} $$
Double factorials can be represented by $\Gamma(n), n\in \mathbb Z/2$ and $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$, so a $\pi$ is around the corner
$$N\left[\frac{\pi }{\prod _{k=1}^{12100} \frac{(2 k)^2}{4 k^2-1}}\right]=2.00004$$
and indeed there are the classical examples
Gradshtein/Rhyzik
0.262
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{(2 k)^2}) = \frac{2}{\pi}$$
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{(2 k+1)^2}) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
Source:
Григо́рий Миха́йлович Фихтенгольц Gregory Fikhtengol'ts
Kurs differentsial’nogo i integral’nogo ischisleniya
(Course in differential and integral calculus), vols. I, II, and III. Gostekhizdat, Moscow and Leningrad, 1947–1949.
German edition:
Fichtenholz, G. M., Differential-und Integralrechnung I–III, VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften, Berlin, 1986–1987.
After a look at 401: Its of course a deformation of the Wallis product
 $$\prod _n\quad \frac{2n}{2n-1} \ \frac{2n}{2n+1} $$

This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is about $\prod _{k=1}^{\color{red}{1008}} \frac{(2 k)^2}{4 k^2-1}$.

This is likely too much for a math olympiad, and in the end only gives an approximate answer anyway, but I thought I'd leave it here nonetheless since it is quite simple computationally and does indeed give the answer to more than two decimal places (though proving that fact without knowing the correct answer ahead of time would require some work).

First, notice that the product can be written as $$\frac1{2017}\left(\frac{2016!!}{2015!!}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2n+1}\left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right)^2$$
for $n = 1008$. We can write this in terms of ordinary factorials using the identities $(2n)!! = 2^n n!$, and $(2n-1)!! = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!}$, which yields
$$\frac1{2n+1}\left(\frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right)^2$$
Now we use Stirling's approximation, which says that $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e}\right)^n$. Hence,
$$\frac1{2n+1}\left(\frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right)^2 \sim \frac1{2n+1}\left(\sqrt{\pi n}\right)^2 = \frac{\pi n}{2n+1}$$
It's worth noting that, in general, $f \sim g$ only says that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$, and so it is entirely possible (and common) that the difference $f(x) - g(x)$ tends to infinity. That is, asymptotics are generally good for understanding orders of magnitude, not for precise numerical estimates as you want here. However, since we derived this relation by applying Stirling's approximation to both the numerator and denominator, the net effect is that we indeed find a rather good numerical approximation to the actual answer. In this case $(n=1008)$, that is $\frac{1008\pi}{2017} = 1.57001...$ A cursory check shows that this is accurate to $3$ decimal places.

Edit:
The more precise version of Stirling's approximation is:
$$\sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \exp\left(\frac1{12n}-\frac1{360n^2} \right) < n! < \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \exp\left(\frac1{12n}\right)$$
Hence,
$$2\pi n \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n} \exp\left(\frac1{6n}-\frac1{180n^2} \right) < (n!)^2 < 2\pi n \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n} \exp\left(\frac1{6n}\right)$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n}} \left(\frac{e}{2n}\right)^{2n} \exp\left(-\frac1{24n} \right) < \frac{1}{(2n)!} < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n}} \left(\frac{e}{2n}\right)^{2n} \exp\left(-\frac1{24n}+\frac1{1440n^2} \right)$$
Since all quantities are positive, it follows that
$$\frac{n\pi}{2n+1}\exp\left(\frac1{3n}-\frac1{12n}-\frac1{90n^2}\right) < \frac1{2n+1}\left(\frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right)^2 < \frac{n\pi}{2n+1}\exp\left(\frac1{3n} - \frac1{12n} + \frac1{720n^2} \right)$$
Putting $n=1008$ gives:
$$1.57... < \frac1{2017}\left(\frac{2016!!}{2015!!}\right)^2 < 1.57...$$
and so it is accurate to $2$ decimal places.

Anyone care to explain the downvote? Is there a problem with the answer?

@I didn't downvote but a possible explanation is the next one: if the limit is 1.57 then it doesn't follow that for $n=1008$ the error is less than $0.01$. Hence it's not a full answer.

Can you please complete your answer with a proof of your 'cursory check'?

@AnneBauval I just numerically calculated both quantities as compared. As I mentioned in the beginning of the post, more work would be required to verify the accuracy. For reference, I edited the post to include how the estimate could be verified.

The other answers seem to use approximations that you would not have seen at a high school olympiad level. This should be a more reasonable solution.
You were on the right track. You've already shown at the product is equal to
$$\left[\frac {2^{1007} \times 1007!} {3 \times 5 \times 7 \times \dots\times2015}\right]^2 \times \frac {2016^2} {2017}$$
It would be nice if you could express the denominator in terms of some factorials too, in fact:
$$3\times5\times\dots\times2015=\frac{2015!}{2^{1007} \times 1007!}$$, so the product becomes:
$$\left[\frac {(2^{1007} \times 1007!)^2} {2015!}\right]^2 \times \frac {2016^2} {2017}$$
If you take out the $2015$ from the denominator, you will get (along with some other terms) $$\frac{2^{2014}}{2014\choose 1007}$$
You mentioned that you are allowed access to a graphing calculator. The above fraction will be the reciprocal of a probability of 1007 successes given $p=\frac12$ in a binomial distribution. If you use the binomial pdf function on your calculator will be able to calculate the value of the scary fraction, and after squaring and adding back the other terms you'll get your answer to 2 decimal places.
